# Regex, matching pattern '1AA11AA111'

Tags: regex

I've just learnt the basics of RegEx and come up with the following Regular Expression

```
"^\\d[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{3}$"
```

to match the specified pattern. It is working absolute fine. My question is, what are the other alternative ways to achieve the same?

Comment: Define better.. Faster at processing? Fewer characters? Easier to comprehend?

Comment: Anything.. as I'm learning... I want to understand the alternative solutions.

Comment: Then say "what other solutions are there to match this pattern" instead of "is there a better way".

Comment: Alter the question as suggested. Rookie mistake.. sorry !

Comment: I'm just a random guy reading this question and asking myself: why there aren't 3 comments explaining 3 down votes? If OP edited original answer, why this is still negatived?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use capture groups and back reference them

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/FURaYI/1)

```
(\d)([A-Z])\2\1{2}\2{2}\1{3}
```

`(\d)`     : capture one digit

`([A-Z])`  : capture word , length of 1

`([A-Z])\2 => \2` : match second found group, 1 time which was found with `([A-Z])`

`\1{2}`    : match first found group, 1 time which was found with `(\d)`

`\2{2}`    : match second found group, 2 times which was found with `([A-Z])`

`\1{3}`    : match first found group, 3 times which was found with `(\d)`

Note : `\1` `\2` are like identities given to groups `()`

Update : to capture specific case sensitive character , just avoid the case insensitive flag i.e. `/i` or to capture only specific type use `([a-z])` or `([A-Z])` which is better because `\w` mean capture these `a-zA-Z0-9_`

Comment: Specifically capture groups _and_ backreferences

Comment: (\w) matches numbers as well. I don't want it that way. It should be specific to upper/lower case letters only.

Comment: @NishanthSreedhara then you can use `([A-Z]){2}` and for lower case `([a-z]){2}` and for both `([A-Za-z]){2}`

Comment: @PavneetSingh thanx, I learnt about back reference through your solution. :)

Comment: @NishanthSreedhara i am glad to read your comment , your welcome

Comment: I tried your solution in RegEx101, it is not working. I tried, but I'm something.. could you please help @PavneetSingh

Comment: @NishanthSreedhara check out the `regexdemo` link please

Comment: @PavneetSingh Ok, I understood now ! It only matches the specific letter matched in the group. If its some thing like '1ay06rm987', it wouldn't match.

Comment: @NishanthSreedhara yeah and i modified it little bit more to make it more clear and precise so you can again click on `regexdemo` to see modified version

Comment: Thank you so much @PavneetSingh